# Problem when trying to intialize a vector as a class member

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I am trying to initialize a vector like this:

```
    std::vector<u8> ConstPldData =
        { 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x35, 0x31, 0x34, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x38, 0x31, 0x30 };
```

But I always get the same error:

```
error: could not convert '{48, 48, 48, 50, 48, 53, 49, 52, 48, 48, 48, 56, 49, 48}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<unsigned char>'
```

Any clues?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version of the compiler? What flags and options do you have when building? What you show is valid since the C++11 standard, so either you have a very old compiler, or you don't have the right flags/options set when building to use the C++11 (or later) standard.

Comment: `ConstPldData` doesn't use **`const`** `std::vector`... strange.

Comment: That error message is consistent with a pre-C++11 compiler.   So I agree with Someprogrammerdude - either your compiler predates C++11, or you are building in a pre-C++11 mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are not compiling in C++11 (or higher). I can only reproduce this error if I pass `-std=c++98` to my compiler settings.